# Boundedness of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I am asked to give an example of a continuous function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that has an image which is unbounded.  I give the function $f(x)=1/x, (0,1)$.  It is bounded below by $0$ and is unbounded above.

I am then asked to explain why this theorem does not apply here:"The image of a continuous function on a closed bounded interval $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above.  That is, there is a number $M$ s.t. $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Is the reason that this theorem does not work that the interval is not bounded?  If not, what is the real reason?

Comment: As I put in my answer below,  are you talking about the image of [a,b] or (a,b)?  Very different things

Comment: You might want to look at the _extreme value theorem_

Comment: Here is a link: [Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is bounded above, by $e^{100}$, or any larger number.

Are you looking for a function that's unbounded on [a,b] or (a,b)?  If the former,  I don't think you'll find one, as the continuous image of a compact set (of which [a,b] is one) has extreme values, and thus is bounded.  If the latter,  try $f(x)=\frac 1 x$,  from (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function $f$ from a compact set $K$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded.  To show this, cover $K$ with $f^{-1}(U_n)$ where $U_n=\{x:|x|\gt n\}$. The existence of a finite subcover shows that $f$ must be bounded.

The [Heine-Borel Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) says that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Thus, $[0,1]$ is compact, but $(0,1)$ is not compact.